# Wrong content for URL cache on Google

Tags: google-search, google-index, cache

I have this website `natural-track.com` and when I do a cache check I get a completely different website,This is Google's cache of http://www.backpackers-planet.com/modules.php?name=Web_Links&l_op=visit&lid=3379 , unrelated to my site. I have checked with the host, they say all is well on their side.

How can we fix it? The site also went off from Google Search. We are about to rebuild this site to a better professional platform but first we would like to have an idea of what happened and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.backpackers-planet.com/modules.php?name=Web_Links&l_op=visit&lid=3379` redirects to `http://www.natural-track.com/`.

And Google’s [cached version of `http://www.natural-track.com/`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache%3anatural-track.com) also corresponds to the page `http://www.natural-track.com/`.

Comment: Indeed, and its a temporary 302 redirect (as opposed to permanent 301) so that's why its causing odd issues.

Comment: Thank you for the info. The 302 redirect, did we cause it or it is from google? What can or should we do to correct it? Sure traffic has gone completely for the last 3 weeks.

Comment: @user32592: The page on `backpackers-planet.com` 302-redirects to `http://www.natural-track.com/`. It’s totally up to the webmasters of `backpackers-planet.com` what they do (which redirect; if to redirect at all). There is nothing to "correct" from your side.

Comment: @moobot Upon reading more and more on forums, could this 302 redirect from the backpacker site be a spammer? (I fail to understand why/how to have  redirect, with a site that is not related to us)

Comment: Perhaps, but like yourself, I fail to see what it would archive. It could just be a mistake, I'd contact the website ASAP and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Actually I have written to the webmaster 4 days ago, but no response so far. Will keep trying. Thanks.